# Get Eureka instance metadata in browser

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Boot (2.4) app (a generic service) and a Eureka discovery server running. The server doesn't register itself as an instance. I am able to navigate to the Eureka dashboard at the default location of `localhost:8761` to get an overview of all the registered instances. I successfully see the service is registered in Eureka. However, this dashboard doesn't give any details about the instance except the name and the port number. I want to be able to see the instance meta data. Is this possible using the dashboard? O maybe there is some exposed URL by the Eureka server that I can call in a browser or postman? Or is there an URL available in the Eureka client (the service) that gives details about its Eureka metadata?

I read thet feign clients access *something* to be able to query the registry. Can I mimic this as human in a browser?

Answer (score 3):

Go to localhost:8761/eureka/apps